# Say to user when app stay "saving" (Method.call is running and not completed)

Tags: javascript, meteor

A kind of google docs that says "Saving..." when user edit text. Or all kind of web site that uses ajax and has to save something on server.

I have understand that Meteor save on MongoDB (server side) through Method.Call (not stubs). But how can know when all method.call (write to db) are ended? (not on client side (minimongo))

**EDIT:**

In my case, there are 3 Method for CRUD operations, defined on client and server:

- Insert
- Update
- Remove

I would that user is notified with a "saving..." message, while this method running on server.

Could be use the async callback when call method from client?

Comment: Have you solved it? If you don't want to include a call back function each time you call a method, consider currying the callback https://medium.com/the-javascript-collection/ce6da2d324fe

Answer (score 1):

The async callback is indeed what you want. In the simplest case:

```
Session.set("theThingIsLoading", true);
Meteor.call("doTheThing", function (error, result) {
    if (error) {/* report it somehow */}
    Session.set("theThingIsLoading", false);
});

{{#if theThingIsLoading}}
    <p>Loading...</p>
{{/if}}
```

Where `theThingIsLoading` is a helper which does `Session.get("theThingIsLoading")`.

Comment: Yeah, I had think to this solution, but I hoped there is a better way. I have many methods that write on db...but if there aren't alternatives : ) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the atmosphere package "auto nprogress". It will show a fancy loading bar at the top of the screen when an action is processed.

Hope it's kind of what you're looking for!

https://atmospherejs.com/package/auto-nprogress

Comment: Thanks! But I know it. And i think work only on subscription...non for method.call... I think have to use async callback of method

Answer (score 0):

I think user3374348's answer could lead to strange behavior if multiple methods are called. 
I suggest:

```
increaseOngoingMethods=function(){
    Session.set("ongoingMethods")=Session.get("ongoingMethods")+1;
}

decreaseOngoingMethods=function(){
    Session.set("ongoingMethods")=Session.get("ongoingMethods")-1;
}

increaseOngoingMethods();
Meteor.call("doTheThing", decreaseOngoingMethods);


UI.registerHelper('Methodsareongoing', function() {
    return !!Session.get("ongoingMethods")
});

{{#if Methodsareongoing}}
    <p>Loading...</p>
{{/if}}
```

Note:

No paranthesis on the callback function in the methodcall.

No var in front of the declaration of the increase and decrease functions - that way they should become globally available.

Methodsareongoing is available in all templates due to the UI.registerHelper

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Andrew Mao's comment made me realize that I probably misunderstood the question!
If you want a 'saving' status showing **one** place this answer is very wrong...
This answer assumes you want to show something like:

John Smith **saving**

Where John Smith is part of the contextual object.

If that is not the case - please see my other answer

*Original answer:*

Have you tried using the 'isSimulation' property?

```
{{#if isSimulation}}
  <b>Saving</b>
{{/if}}
```

If you methods are available on the client as well it should work.
If not - could you please add your methods to this thread

UPDATE:
You updated your post - simple CRUD operations should be able to run on the client.
If you try this but never see the 'saving' bit on your page it is because it is so fast :-/
In the good book Discover Meteor, to illustrate this technique they actully use a fancy delay method so the user is able to see the model simulation...

Comment: Is the same described here: http://docs.meteor.com/#method_issimulation? I have different Method that make some CRUD operation on DB. (ex. insert, update, remove)

Comment: Yes that is the one :) 
Are your methods located in server folder or are they available on the client as well?

Comment: the method are locate for both (on 'share' folder)

Comment: If the methods are able to run on the client (that is they do not rely on some logic only available on the server side) they will run on the client as well (Latency Compensation with model simulation)
The objects will have isSimulation=true until the server returns methods have run

Comment: This is a hugely misleading answer - you cannot use `isSimulation` as a helper in a template. It wouldn't even make sense because you wouldn't know what method it is associated with.

Comment: @AndrewMao Thank you - I think I completely misunderstood the question